# Displaying number of elements inside an array list with a messagebox

Tags: c#, silverlight, arraylist

I have an array list called str, i want to see how many elements there are inside that array list, how should I go about using a messagebox to display that?

Comment: Please add some details and context in code. What is an "array list" ? And why is it called 'str'?

Comment: Hope you looking for `Count` or `Length` or something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just do       for getting the length and display it                 .

```
MessageBox.Show(str.Count.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

[ArrayList.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.count.aspx):

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("str: {0} element(s)", str.Count));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
......
MessageBox.Show(arr.Count.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MessageBox.Show(str.Count.ToString());
```